# displaying data in one page spring mvc

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I do not understand where the problem is, to display the data. He has the title (name, price and quantity), but not the data

here is the controller

```
@Controller
public class ProductListController {

        @Autowired ProductRepository productRepository;

        @RequestMapping("/productlist")
        public ModelAndView showProductList() {
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("productlist");  
            List<Product> list = productRepository.findAll();
            mv.addObject("displayProduct",list);
            return mv;
        }

    }
```

here is the productlist.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<%@  page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@  taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' prefix='c' %>
<%@  taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>

<html>
<head>
   <title>Product</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="displayProduct">
<table border="1" >
 <tr>
   <td>Name</td>
   <td>Price</td>
   <td>Quantity</td>
 </tr>
<c:forEach items="${displayProduct}" var="p">
   <c:out value="${p.name}"/>
</c:forEach>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us your `Product` class.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you render the proper markup.

```
<c:forEach items="${displayProduct}" var="p">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${p.name}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${p.price}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${p.quantity}"/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Also, make sure `productRepository.findAll()` actually returns some results. If it is an empty result set, you will not see anything on the JSP.

Comment: Also, the `form` isn't closed.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the method productRepository.findAll() with the consol way it displays the result and I change my code as you proposed. I have always the same problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<%@  page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@  taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' prefix='c' %>
<%@  taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>

<html>
<head>
   <title>Product</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="displayProduct">
    <h1>Product</h1>

    <table border="1" >

        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td colspan="2">Actions</td>

        </tr>

    <c:forEach items="${displayProduct}" var="p">
       <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${p.name}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${p.price}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${p.quantity}"/></td>
      </tr>
    </c:forEach>


    </table>

    <a href="<c:url value='/'/>">home page</a><br/>
    </form:form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to see your Product object.
Do you have the three getters getName(), getPrice() and getQuantity() in it ?

Your Product pojo must match the JavaBeans naming convention to be used with the JSP expression language: ${p.name}, ${p.price} and ${p.quantity}